# Webpack Encore - Module rules - Error when export/import scss variables into javascript

Tags: javascript, css, symfony, sass, webpack-encore

I try to import scss/css variables into javascript. I stumbled upon [this](https://blog.bluematador.com/posts/how-to-share-variables-between-js-and-sass/) blog post which uses the [`:export` block](https://github.com/css-modules/icss#specification).

I `npm install`ed the `sass-loader` and `node-sass` just to make sure I have them. Now when I use `:export` i get an error telling me that sass isn't valid CSS:

```
$theme-colors: ( 
  "primary": #bc2a0a,
  "secondary": #4B5C74,
  ...
);

:export {
  colorPalette: $theme-colors // Error occurs because of using sass variable
}
```

> Module build failed: ("primary": #bc2a0a, "secondary": #4B5C74, ...) isn't a valid CSS value.

I'm pretty sure this is because of the module rules which I don't know how to apply. My current `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
let Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
let webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    .addEntry('vendors', [
        'react',
        'react-dom',
        'extend',
        'prop-types',
        'jquery',
        'ApiRouter',
        'translator',
        'moment',
        'moment-timezone',
        './vendor/boewa/glyphicons/src/css/glyphicons.css'
    ])

    .addEntry('app', [
        './assets/js/main.js',
        './assets/css/app.scss',
    ])

    .enableSassLoader()
    .enableReactPreset()

    // Some plugins
    .addPlugin(...).addPlugin(...)

    .autoProvidejQuery()

    .configureFilenames({
        images: '[path][name].[ext]',
    })
;

let config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
config.resolve.alias = {
    'ApiRouter': 'Common/Networking/ApiRouter.js',
    'translator': 'Common/Translator.js'
};
config.resolve.modules = [
    path.resolve('./assets/js'),
    path.resolve('./node_modules')
];

module.exports = config;
```

**So how can I get the `:export` to work so that I can use sass/css variables in javascript?**

Comment: Could you try to add this line to the config?

`.configureCssLoader(function(config) {     
           config.modules= true;
     });`

Comment: I'll do that but no until tuesday, thanks for your appreciation.

Comment: OK let me know how it goes. I suspect that webpack-encore unfortunately lacks a dependency needed for CSS modules to work.

Comment: That's why I asked: `webpack-encore != webpack` :)

Comment: I had go through the source code of that package. Worst case you need to open an issue in their repo to get support for CSS modules, or just create a clean webpack config from scratch

Comment: @ProgrammerPer Webpack encore does not have a `configureCssLoader` function. So there is no current support for CSS modules in webpack encore right?

Comment: I was looking at the source code in version 0.20.1, that's how I spotted the `configureCssLoader` function, but couldn't see that `style-loader` was a dependency. That loaoder is required for CSS modules to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) as a dependency in your project and enable it in your [webpack config](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader).

Here is an [example](https://github.com/css-modules/webpack-demo)